# Repair grub Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

Few days ago grub doesn't work on my computer, to boot Ubuntu I have to select the boot device on the post screen when the computer starts and then grub appears and I can start Ubuntu. How I can repair grub on Ubuntu to appear by default? All tutorials tells how to reinstall it from live CD but I don't need a live CD because I can boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Isn't this a hardware issue?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? How many devises do you have in your PC/Laptop? Do you have UEFI  boot in  Ubuntu? do you have Windows  also?

Comment: ubuntu 18.14, uefi boot and I have windows 10.